# Unable to connect to database on cPanel only

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am unable to connect my script to database on my server (cPanel/WHM)
But the script is working on my localhost WAMP
The database is attached correctly other script is working but only this script is not woorkign
[Screen SHot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6atrJ.png)

Comment: Update your config.php with the cpanel DB credentials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If the database host and host of your application are different: add the ip of your application host to the whitelist (Remote MySQL icon in cPanel)
- Check your credentials
- Check the privileges of the user